# Theorem, subsection, counter

Tags: theorems, setcounter, subsection

I'd like to get only the second subsection of this photo

[image: Theorems Proof]

such that its code is this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\newcommand{\newsubsectheorem}[2]{%
  \newtheorem{#1}{#2}[subsection]%
  \counterwithin{#1}{subsection}}

\newsubsectheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newsubsectheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newsubsectheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Theorem Proof}
\section{Introduction}
See these Theorems:
\subsection{These Theorems}
\newsubsectheorem{First}{First Theorem}
\begin{First}
Theorem with Its Proof.
\end{First}
\newsubsectheorem{Second}{Second Theorem}
\begin{Second}
Theorem with Its Proof.
\end{Second}
\hrule
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\subsection{These Theorems}
\textbf{First Theorem 1.1.1.1} \textit{Theorem with Its Proof.}\vspace{3mm}\\
\textbf{Second Theorem 1.1.1.2} \textit{Theorem with Its Proof.}
\end{document}
```

I hope in you help, thank you so much

Comment: Please, add some details: do you want all theorems to be numbered according to the subsection and you want some theorems to have “nonstandard names”? You *certainly* don't want to issue `\newsubsectheorem` inside the document.

Comment: Sorry, don't get what your current code is, how your current result looks like (screenshot) and how it should differ (graphical sketch) ...

Comment: First subsection is not manually-made, instead the second one (even if keeps the same numbering as the first one) is manually. I'd like to have a tex code that makes the second subsection with this number theorem: chapter.section.subsection.theoremnumber. How Must I do? Thank you and Sorry if my question has not been so clear. Now is it clear?

Comment: @egreg I proofed with \newsubsectheorem but the result is not good...

Comment: @Puck You didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you want to number theorems in general according to the subsection number, which requires very strict subdivisions of your document and makes for clumsy references. And I hope you don't really want to number propositions and lemmas independently of theorems.

Anyway, the following code should be what you want.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\newcommand{\namedtheoremname}{}
\newtheorem{namedtheoreminner}[theorem]{\protect\namedtheoremname}
\newenvironment{namedtheorem}[1]
 {%
  \renewcommand{\namedtheoremname}{#1}%
  \begin{namedtheoreminner}%
 }
 {\end{namedtheoreminner}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Theorem Proof}

\section{Introduction}
See these Theorems:

\subsection{These Theorems}

\begin{namedtheorem}{First Theorem}
Theorem with Its Proof.
\end{namedtheorem}

\begin{namedtheorem}{Second Theorem}
Theorem with Its Proof.
\end{namedtheorem}

\subsection{Another}

\begin{theorem}
Theorem with Its Proof.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm also not sure why loading `thmtools` without using any of its features.

Comment: Thank you so much, is thmtools inuseful?